# X1 Carbon with 20.04: no microphone

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, thinkpad, microphone

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on a X1 Carbon. The internal microphone is not recognized. Speakers however are recognized.

I have seen that this used to be an issue with earlier versions of Ubuntu and earlier versions of the kernel, but a suggestion usually was to upgrade kernel/Ubuntu, which won't help me:

```
$ uname -r
5.4.0-45-generic
```

How could I set up the microphone on this computer? Is there some statistics required to figure out why it's not working?